# Image and several lines of text in bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

It's probably a silly question, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I need to create a bootstrap menu where each item is an image on the left and several lines of text on the right.

I wrote the following HTML for this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="clearfix">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <span>My image</span>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <div>Text on the right</div>
                    <div>Second line of text</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brucecat5/rr71xmry/

However, width is not calculated properly and the second floated block is moved below the first block.

I don't understand why it happens and what to do to fix this.

P.S. I know I can implement it with `display: table-cell`, but I just don't understand the reason why my approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is how you use dropdown-menu class, try this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<ul style="display: block;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <p>Text on the right</p>
                <p>Second line of text</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you want use a dropdown-menu, you can look an example in this page:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_button_groups.asp

Hope it helps.